# Titanium with how to run some code when user click on the notification? (Android)

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, titanium

how to run some code when user click on the notification? if user click push notification i want understand coming from push notification.

How can i do?

Thanks
-Gcm Module-
    //my gcm module
    var gcm = require("nl.vanvianen.android.gcm");

```
    /* If the app is started or resumed act on pending data saved when the notification was received */
    var lastData = gcm.getLastData();
    if (lastData) {
        Ti.API.info("Last notification received " + JSON.stringify(lastData));
        gcm.clearLastData();
    }

    gcm.registerPush({

        senderId : 'xxxxxxxx',
        notificationSettings : {
            sound : 'mysound.mp3',
            smallIcon : 'notification_icon.png',
            largeIcon : 'appicon.png',
            vibrate : true
        },
       //Push registration success
        success : function(event) {
            Ti.API.info("Push registration success: " + JSON.stringify(event));

        },
//Push registration error
        error : function(event) {
            Ti.API.info("Push registration error = " + JSON.stringify(event));
            alert(event.error);
        },
        //i want this function Coming from push
        data : function(event) {

            // console.log(" ******* Coming from push : " + JSON.stringify(event));


        },
       //my callback funtion call device token
        callback : function(event) {
            Ti.API.info("Push callback = " + JSON.stringify(event));

            var dialog = Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
                title : 'Push received',
                message : JSON.stringify(event.data)

                // buttonNames: ['View'],
                // cancel: 1

            });
            dialog.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
                dialog.hide();
                if (event.index == 0) {
                    /* Do stuff to view the notification */
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        },
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Titanium.UI.setBackgroundColor('#000');

var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor : '#ccc',
    title : 'Android Cloud Push Notification'
});

var CloudPush = require('ti.cloudpush');
CloudPush.debug = true;
CloudPush.enabled = true;
CloudPush.showTrayNotification = true;
CloudPush.showTrayNotificationsWhenFocused = true;
CloudPush.focusAppOnPush = false;

var deviceToken;
var Cloud = require('ti.cloud');
Cloud.debug = true;

var submit = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title : 'Register For Push Notification',
    color : '#000',
    height : 53,
    width : 200,
    top : 100,
});

win.add(submit);

submit.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    CloudPush.retrieveDeviceToken({
        success : function deviceTokenSuccess(e) {
            alert('Device Token: ' + e.deviceToken);
            deviceToken = e.deviceToken;
            loginDefault();
        },
        error : function deviceTokenError(e) {
            alert('Failed to register for push! ' + e.error);
        }
    });
});

function loginDefault(e) {
    // At first you need to create an user from the application dashboard 
    // Then login that email and password
    Cloud.Users.login({
        login : '.....',
        password : '....'
    }, function(e) {
        if (e.success) {
            alert("login success");
            defaultSubscribe();
        } else {
            alert('Error: ' + ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
        }
    });
}

function defaultSubscribe() {
    Cloud.PushNotifications.subscribe({
        channel : 'alert',
        device_token : deviceToken,
        type : 'android'
    }, function(e) {
        if (e.success) {
            alert('Subscribed for Push Notification!');
        } else {
            alert('Error:' + ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
        }
    });
}

CloudPush.addEventListener('callback', function(evt) {
    //alert(evt);
    //alert(evt.payload);
});

CloudPush.addEventListener('trayClickLaunchedApp', function(evt) {
    Ti.API.info('Tray Click Launched App (app was not running)');
    //alert('Tray Click Launched App (app was not running');
});

CloudPush.addEventListener('trayClickFocusedApp', function(evt) {
    Ti.API.info('Tray Click Focused App (app was already running)');
    //alert('Tray Click Focused App (app was already running)');
});

win.open();
```

Comment: It also successful at the push notification of Appcelerator panel goes one way, but does not mean the device. what should I do?